# Optimise MySql temp table update query

Tags: mysql

Hello I am using temp table and i have slow update sql statement, just wondering is it possible to do some improvements. I have couple of indexes for my temp table.

Here is my query.

```
EXPLAIN UPDATE `unval_chip` AS `T`
 INNER JOIN `checkpoint_timing_mat` AS `P` ON T.timing_mat_id= P.timing_mat_id
 INNER JOIN `checkpoint` AS `C` ON P.checkpoint_id=C.id AND T.race_id=C.race_id
 INNER JOIN `timing_mat` AS `M` ON T.timing_mat_id=M.id
 INNER JOIN `timing_device` AS `D` ON M.timing_device_id=D.id
 INNER JOIN `entry` AS `E` ON T.entry_id=E.id
 INNER JOIN `race` AS `R` ON E.race_id=R.id
 LEFT JOIN `wave` AS `W` ON E.wave_id=W.id
SET  T.usage_type='INVALID',
     T.invalid_reason='has-excluded-time'
WHERE (T.usage_type='VALID')
  AND ((ceil((T.raw_crossing_time/1000 + D.offset) - 
       (IF(W.actual_start_offset IS NULL, R.planned_start_time, coalesce(R.actual_start_time,R.planned_start_time)) +
       coalesce(W.actual_start_offset, W.planned_start_offset, 0))) <=
       C.exclude_before_offset)
     OR (floor((T.raw_crossing_time/1000 + D.offset) -
       (IF(W.actual_start_offset IS NULL, R.planned_start_time, coalesce(R.actual_start_time,R.planned_start_time)) + 
       coalesce(W.actual_start_offset, W.planned_start_offset, 0))) >=
       C.exclude_after_offset)
      )
```

Here what i got from explain [image: Explain output]

This first row for table T shows type "All" and has 179419 rows scanned. Is it possible to do some improvements there?

Here is what i tried actually, added index on "usage_type" column, and got like 50% less rows which should be scanned. But that column is ENUM type. But overall execution time increased. I am little bit confused, how that happened? Any hint is more than welcomed?

Here is temp table structure

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `unval_chip` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `chip_nbr` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `timing_mat_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `raw_crossing_time` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `event_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `race_id` bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `entry_id` bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `lap` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `usage_type` enum('NEW','INVALID','VALID','FORCE_USE','FORCE_SKIP','DELETED') DEFAULT 'VALID',
  `invalid_reason` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_processed` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `mtime` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  KEY `ix_rs_id` (`id`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `ix_rs_event_id` (`event_id`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `ix_rs_race_id` (`race_id`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `ix_rs_entry_id` (`entry_id`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `ix_rs_timing_mat_id` (`timing_mat_id`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `ix_rs_chip_nbr` (`chip_nbr`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `ix_rs_raw_crossing_time` (`raw_crossing_time`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Here is second table i think that other tables are good.

```
CREATE TABLE `checkpoint_timing_mat` (
  `checkpoint_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `timing_mat_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `priority` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `ctime` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `mtime` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`checkpoint_id`,`timing_mat_id`),
  KEY `FK_cptm_tm` (`timing_mat_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_cptm_cp` FOREIGN KEY (`checkpoint_id`) REFERENCES `checkpoint` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_cptm_tm` FOREIGN KEY (`timing_mat_id`) REFERENCES `timing_mat` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

And here is with additional index for 'usage_type'

[image]

And without joins
[image]

And with composite index

[image]

Comment: yes it looks odd

Comment: Updated the question

Comment: @Strawberry added two tables from top, i think thats enough since we should focus on this type "ALL"?

Comment: So T has no PRIMARY KEY?

Comment: Yes tried to add PK, but same thing like 20k rows are affected, takes 13 seconds

Comment: CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE unval_chip (invalid_reason varchar(255), PRIMARY KEY `ix_rs_id` (id) USING BTREE, INDEX `ix_rs_event_id` (event_id) USING BTREE >>>

Comment: I have a rather unscientfic approach to indexing, so, I would get rid of ix_rs_timing_mat_id, and replace ix_rs_id with your pk declaration, and stick an index on some combination of (timing_mat_id,race_id,entry_id,usage_type)

Comment: I think that mysql optimiser knows that indexing enums is not best practice

Comment: It's not the data type, but rather the number of different values that matters when it comes to considering whether the index is useful. If I have a book with two indexes: things that begin with 'a', and things that don't, then that's probably not very useful. But if it has 26 categories, then maybe that's more useful.

Comment: Well it has 6 values

Comment: @Strawberry yes thats right

Comment: @Strawberry look like joins are the main issue

Comment: @Strawberry but adding index reduce that number to 80 k thats still a lot.

Comment: Well, it's less than half, which feels like a step in the right direction. I'd be curious to see the revised schema and corresponding EXPLAIN for that.

Comment: @Strawberry added picture, what i did is ALTER TABLE `unval_chip` ADD KEY `rrrrr` (usage_type) USING BTREE; its for 40 row set so it something like 50%. But getting increased execution time.

Comment: (usage_type)? You mean (timing_mat_id,race_id,entry_id,usage_type)?

Comment: its enum `usage_type` enum('NEW','INVALID','VALID','FORCE_USE','FORCE_SKIP','DELETED') DEFAULT 'VALID',

Comment: Sure, but the index is a composite: `ALTER TABLE unval_chip ADD KEY rrrrr (timing_mat_id,race_id,entry_id,usage_type) ` (and all the other steps I mentioned)

Comment: @Strawberryyou think that i should try with composite index?

Comment: Is that a rhetorical question?

Comment: @Strawberry not check last picture, and first line in explain command it's type "all".

Comment: Without seeing the revised CREATE TABLE statement, I find this a bit hard to follow